# Given a function and its transformed graph, find an equation of the transformation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, graphing-functions

Given a parent function and its transformed graph, I need to find an equation of the transformation.

[image]

I cant seem to figure #13 or #14... I get confused with which points to start with when dealing with reflections espectially with translations because the reflections makes it confusing. In addition the the dilations as well.